# how to update Records using nsupdate?

Tags: linux, bind

We know that we can update a record (its IP) by doing these steps:

```
nsupdate
server ns.bar44.com
zone bar44.com
update delete somehost.bar44.com. A
update add somehost.bar44.com. 86400 A 10.10.10.1
show
send
```

1. As we can see we know that the somehost.bar44.com. is exist in the DB, this will work if I want to update the IP of an existing Record, but what if I want to change the hostname not the IP. E.g., I want to make 10.10.10.1 the IP of somehost22.bar44.com. what will let me know that IP is already taken by somehost.bar44.com.?
2. Is this a way to delete the whole DB of a certain zone using nsupdate?

Comment: What's the issue you are facing ??, what's the issue if two hosts has same ip ?

Comment: I want to give a machine with a specific IP different names which I extract from a dynamic DB

Comment: so you want to find let say `somehost22.bar44.com` and delete the same and update `somehost.bar44.com` ? is it ?

Comment: yes, delete the the host with the IP I want to add if it exist and add it simply if not @RahulPatil

Comment: Ok.. is AXFR query is allowed ?

Comment: if yes how can I make use of it, and is this the option that make it work `provide-ixfr = yes` @RahulPatil

Comment: we can make shell script, which will execute AXFR query to your dns server for checking that IP and domain exists or not and performed accordingly

Comment: So just check `dig somehost22.bar44.com @yourdnsip`

Comment: dear I'll be back after half an hour.. and will try to create that script in my side and update you soon..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***DISCLAIMER**: use this script on your own risk*

---

**What it does?**

As O/P wants, lets say he wants to add `somedomain.bar44.com` and `somedomain44.bar44.com` already exists in the zone then it should first remove `somedomain44.bar44.com` and then re-add `somedomain.bar44.com` into the zone. The script below does just that. Tested on Ubuntu with BIND9.

In short, it will add `xyz.bar.com` if it does not exist yet and if it exists then it will first remove (`xyz*.bar.com`) and then re-add with the new information provided by you.

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
#
## Update DNS Records Interactive
## Rahul Patil <http://www.linuxian.com>

#
## Functions
#

ask() {
    
    while [[ $ans == "" ]]
    do
        read -p "${@}"  ans
    done

    echo $ans
}

forward_zone_update() { 
    local rr=${@}
    echo "
    server $DNS_SERVER
    zone $DNS_ZONE
    update add $rr
    show
    send" | nsupdate
}

delete_record() { 
    local rr=${@}
    echo "
    server $DNS_SERVER
    zone $DNS_ZONE
    update delete $rr
    show
    send" | nsupdate
}


#
## Global Variable
#
DNS_IP="127.0.0.1"
DNS_SERVER="ns1.rahul.local"
DNS_ZONE="rahul.local"
DIG_CMD='dig +noquestion +nocmd +nostat +nocomments'

update_rr_a=$( ask "Enter FQDN of Record (Ex. xyz.${DNS_ZONE}) :-")
update_rr=$( ask "Enter IP of Record :-")
found_rr=$($DIG_CMD @${DNS_IP} AXFR ${DNS_ZONE} | grep  ^"${update_rr_a%.$DNS_ZONE}" | tee /tmp/rr.tmp )

echo "Checking ${update_rr_a}..."

if [[ -z "${found_rr}" ]] 
then
    echo "${update_rr_a} does exists"
    echo "${update_rr_a} adding to ${DNS_ZONE}"
    forward_zone_update "${update_rr_a} 86400 IN A ${update_rr}"
    echo "Done!!"
else
    echo "${update_rr_a} already exists"
    ans=$(ask "Do you want to Delete RR and want to re-add(y/n?)")
    case $ans in
        [yY]|[yY][eE][sS]) while read r; 
                   do delete_record $r ; 
                               done < /tmp/rr.tmp ;;

        [nN]|[nN][oO])     exit 1 ;;
    esac
    forward_zone_update "${update_rr_a} 86400 IN A ${update_rr}"
    echo "Done!!"
fi
```

Comment: thanks but why the script will be risky?

Comment: As per your requirement it's Okay, but suppose somebody want to use and requirement bit different, then it will be risky, suppose he want to remove only `xyz11.bar.com` not `xyz.bar.com`, then he will lost `xyz.bar.com` info only have last updated `xyz11.bar.com`, but after testing on staging anyone can easily modify and use the same.. I hope you understood

Comment: As a side note, you can always do a delete. If the subdomain doesn't exist, then nothing happens. So always delete + add works just fine. No need for the `grep` to see whether we should do a delete or not.